# Creating Virtual Desktop Collections on server 2012 r2- VM Template not getting listed

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We are evaluating VDI solution and I have done the initial setups but still the sysprep vhd not showing in template.

Comment: you should probably put a little more effort on describing what you are talking about, so someone can actually helps you.

Comment: i want to deploy the VDI from remote desktop services , i did all the setup like 1: deployed server 2012 r2 2: deploy ADDS 3: deployed Hyper-v 4: deployed RDS 5: deployed the Virtual machine on hyper-v and sysprep it and VM is shutdown . I have configure all this thing on same server , but when i try to deploy the Virtual Desktop Collections pool not showing Creating Virtual Desktop templates there.